# Why was Tyrion worried & disapproving of Jon and Dany’s actions on the boat?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In S07E07, “The Dragon and the Wolf”, of *Game of Thrones*,

> Jon ends up in Daenerys's bed-chambers. They end up having sex.

We see Tyrion noticing this & there is a worried look on his face and clear disapproval.

In S08E01, “Winterfell”, when Ser Davos proposes their marriage, Tyrion comments that they make a lovely couple.

Earlier, when Dany is sailing for Westeros, Tyrion advices her to leave her lover Daario behind as Dany can enter alliances through marriage.

There is only Cersei & Jon left at that point to form potential alliance. Tyrion knows Jon well & considers him as a good & honorable & standup guy.

So, why would he be worried and he disapprove of this?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Tyrion, Jon and Dany ending up together is a spoiler no. Or have we given up completely

Comment: Reword it if you want but that 3 characters end up together is less of a spoiler than “boatsex”.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot "boatsex" has no meaning to a fan who hasn't seen S07 yet. So, it doesn't spoil anything & the title still makes sense for people who are up to date. If a fan explicitly searches for boatsex meaning on Google & gets spoiled, its his responsibility. Over at M&TV.SE, we are extra cautious with spoilers. I havn't been a regular at SciFi.SE for quiet  a while so don't know how you guys handle spoilers now

Comment: We’re cautious with spoilers to but there is a limit to be made where you stop otherwise you end up with meaningless titles.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot but both my titles(here and the bronn question) made sense for fans who are up-to-date with the episodes & yet were spoiler free to the fans that didn't know. Anyway, no point continuing this discussion here. You know more about community of SciFi then me

Comment: Jon didn't use foreplay, naturally, Tyrion disapproves.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Because Tyrion loves Dany

In the official script for Season 7 Episode 4, “The Spoils of War”, the script reads as follows:

> The brother he loves races towards his probable death at the hands of the queen Tyrion also loves.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 7 Episode 4, “The Spoils of War”</sub>

The scripts were provided to the Writers Guild of America West, you can see the full context [here](https://www.digitalspy.com/tv/ustv/a25420707/game-of-thrones-tyrion-loves-daenerys-confirmed/):

> For season 6 episode 10 'The Winds of Winter', the script reads at one point: "Dany is staring into the distance so Tyrion is able to watch her from up close. Goddamn but she is beautiful.
>
> "He watches her for a beat too long and turns away. Lost in her own thoughts, she doesn't notice that he's flustered."
>
> Season 7 episode 4 'The Spoils of War' makes this even more obvious. During the scene where Tyrion watches Jaime putting himself in mortal danger by charging at Daenerys and her dragon Drogon, the script says: "The brother he loves races towards his probable death at the hands of the queen Tyrion also loves."

Comment: FWIW I thought the Inside the Episode for Episode 1 had something about Tyrion and Dany but either I’m missing something when I watched it or I’m making it up

Comment: Note that 'love' need not imply romantic/sexual love. Tyrion does not 'love' Jaime in the way Cersei does, he just loves him as a friend and brother. However, the quote about Tyrion getting flustered over Dany's beauty seems much less ambiguous.

Comment: Love can be in various forms. I don't feel he loves Dany sexually, maybe protectively as a adult figure to her. He admires Jon. Anyway, If it was his protective instincts, its understandable. If it's jealousy, the writers appear to have forgotten about it. Alt-Shift-X mentioned that Tyrion loves Dany. Maybe that's where you got the idea

Comment: @KharoBangdo _"Alt-Shift-X mentioned that Tyrion loves Dany. Maybe that's where you got the idea"_ Never heard of Alt-Shift-X but in either case I didn't get the "idea" from anywhere I am quoting from the script.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to copy/paste my old answer from this [Movie.stackexchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79608/why-did-tyrion-look-displeased) question. I believed it back then and S08E02 only confirms my theory even more for myself after seeing Daenerys her reaction when Jon told her what Bran and Sam had told him.

---

I believe Tyrion knows about Jon's parents.

That is why he looks so confused. On one hand, he wants a next in line for Daenarys, on the other, he feels this is wrong, especially because they (Dany and Jon) don't know. Unlike Cersei and Jaime did.

**How**
Varys told him...
How does Varys know? In season 1, Varys visits Ned Stark a few times in his cell. On the last visit, Varys informs him that they will let him "take the black" and live out his days with his bastard son if he pleads guilty and asks for mercy.
Ned asks for one last favor and asks for ink and paper. In 7 season, it has never been revealed what was in that letter or to who it was written too.
He most likely wrote it for Jon or about Jon, so that he didn't take the truth with him to his grave.
Why would he risk this with Varys?

- Varys use to advise the Targaryen Mad King, so he was originally a Targaryen supporter.
- Jon is relatively safe at The Wall from the Lannisters claws if it gets out.
- Varys seems to be the only ally Ned has at that moment.

After 7 seasons, that letter is forgotten by most viewers so that it will have enough shock effect when it is revealed.
Varys trusts Tyrion, so it would not be such a surprise that he told him.
But why would they keep it a secret?

They have no proof other than Ned Starks letter.
They have no reason to reveal this to either Dany or Jon, it could only bring internal disputes.

**Why**
If Daenerys has to hear this truth from a crippled boy with visions and a drop out maester who is in the Night's Watch, she will be skeptical about it, like she is about everything without proof.
But if 2 of her trusted advisors confirm this news, she will be more open to the truth.
Varys was also the Spider when serving the Mad King, he most likely knew the truth behind Rheagar and Lyanna's relationship and might even know about their secret wedding.
Let Howland Reed visit Wintefell at that same time and confirm that Ned came out of that tower with baby Jon, and all the North will believe it too, because everyone knows the story of how Ned killed Ser Arthur Dayne with Howland Reed at his side.

The big "Jon is a Targaryen" reveal must be well supported, not just to convince Dany, but everyone who is convinced before it is revealed is one less doubter and easier to explain why they will all accept this story as truth.